# Converting date formats from Java to SQL

Tags: java, sql

I have an input field in a Java Swing form that accepts a date in the following format

dd/mm/yyyy

I use the following to convert it in to a SQL date format

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
java.util.Date inputDate = format.parse(date);
sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(inputDate.getTime());
```

However in my SQL table, the dates are written as 2020-12-12. How do I change this? I know that I am probably using some legacy types here but it's not production code and so that doesn't matter to me at the moment.

Comment: If the data type of the column in your database is an actual date type (i.e. not a varchar), then the format that you see when looking at your data is just a product of how the DBMS software chooses to display it.  If you can save/read data to/from the database, then how it's formatted when you view the table contents is unimportant.

Comment: Do not longer use the old `java.util.date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Use the modern `DateFormatter` and classes from `java.time` package

Comment: Are you getting the format from running a SQL against the database and seeing the result? Or is it really not a date, but some string column?

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.parse( 
    "23/01/2020" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) 
)
.toString()
```

> 2020-01-23

## Avoid legacy classes

Do not use the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.sql.Date`, and `SimpleDateFormat`. These became outmoded with the adoption of JSR 310.

Use only the modern *java.time* classes.

## *java.time*

Parse your input string as a `LocalDate`. This class represents a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
String input = "23/01/2020" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

## Database

> However in my SQL table, the dates are written as 2020-12-12.

You should be using a date-time data type when defining such a column in your database. The SQL-standard type is `DATE`. Your database likely has either that exact type name or something by another name.

As of JDBC 4.2, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

But if you are really writing the date values as text in YYYY-MM-DD format, then you should know that format complies with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. That standard format is used by default when parsing/generating text with the *java.time* classes. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;
```

And parsing.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2020-01-23" ) ;
```

All this has been covered many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static java.sql.Date dataSQL( final java.util.Date dataNormal ) {

    if( dataNormal == null ){
        log.warn("Erro classe Util");
        throw new InvalidParameterException( "Artefato: UtilDatas, Metodo: dataSQL(), " +
                null." );
    }

    Calendar data = Calendar.getInstance();
    data.setTime( dataNormal );
    data.set( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
    data.set( Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
    data.set( Calendar.SECOND, 0 );
    data.set( Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0 );

    java.sql.Date dataSQL = new java.sql.Date( data.getTimeInMillis() );

    return dataSQL;
}
```

Comment: Do not suggest to use the old `Calendar` and `java.util.Date` class

Comment: FYI, the terribly flawed date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. Suggesting their use in 2020 is poor advice.